# ASAN: can I have both -fsanitize=address and LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libasan.so on same file

Tags: gcc, address-sanitizer

I'm compiling a program with `-fsanitize=address`, but getting error

```
==48458==ASan runtime does not come first in initial library list; you should either link runtime to your application or manually preload it with LD_PRELOAD.
```

After adding `LD_PRELOAD`, its working fine, but if I'm using `LD_PRELOAD` do I need `-fsanitize=address` compiler flag as well?

After adding `LD_PRELOAD`, should I still compile my program with `-fsanitize=address` flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `-fsanitize=address` inserts additional instrumentation in your code which is used to detect memory errors. You definitely want to keep it.